# How to use vue-draggable (or Sortable JS) in a v-data-table with Vuetify 2 and Vue JS 2?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, datatable, vuetify.js, v-data-table

I'm trying to use vue-draggable with Vuetify v-data-table by following this article :
https://medium.com/vuetify/drag-n-drop-in-vuetify-part-ii-2b07b4b27684

It says : "The main goal was to set tbody of table as draggable component and it was not possible because Vuetify uses template as a slot for rendering items."

After that, the guy found a solution with Sortable JS.
I tried it but it's not working.

this error appears : Sortable: el must be an HTMLElement, not [object Function].

People are saying that Sortable JS is not working for Vue JS 2...

How can I do ?

If you have a solution please let me know :)

My code :

> ```
>     <v-data-table
>       :headers="headers"
>       :items="slots"
>       :items-per-page="-1"
>       ref="sortableTable"
>     >
>       <template v-slot:item="props">
>         <tr v-if="props.item.recipe" class="sortableRow">
>           <td style="text-align: center">{{props.item.slot}}</td>
>           <td style="text-align: center" v-if="props.item.recipe.preferences">
>             <v-chip
>             v-for="pref in props.item.recipe.preferences"
>             :key="pref"
>             small
>           >
>             {{ pref }}
>           </v-chip>
>           </td>
>           <td style="text-align: center">{{props.item.recipe.protein}}</td>
>           <td style="text-align: center">{{props.item.recipe.protein_cut}}</td>
>           <td style="text-align: center">{{props.item.recipe.carb}}</td>
>           <td style="text-align: center" v-if="props.item.recipe.tags">
>             <v-chip
>               v-if="props.item.recipe.tags.indexOf('c3_appropriate') !== -1"
>               small
>               color="success"
>               text-color="white"
>             >
>               C3
>             </v-chip>
>           </td>
>           <td style="text-align: center">{{props.item.recipe.ready_in}}</td>
>           <td style="text-align: center">
>             <v-chip
>               small
>               :color="props.item.recipe.new_repeat === 'repeat' ? 'error' : 'success'"
>             >
>               {{ props.item.recipe.new_repeat }}
>             </v-chip>
>           </td>
>           <td style="text-align: center">
>             {{ props.item.recipe.title + ' ' }}
>             <span
>               v-if="props.item.recipe.subtitle"
>               style="font-size: 11px"
>             >
>                 <br>
>                 {{ props.item.recipe.subtitle }}
>               </span>
>           </td>
>         </tr>
>         <tr v-else>
>           <td style="text-align: center">{{props.item.slot}}</td>
>         </tr>
>
>       </template>
>     </v-data-table>
>
>
> mounted() {
>
>         let table = document.querySelector("table tbody");
>         console.log(table)
>         const _self = this;
>         Sortable.create(table, {
>             draggable: '.sortableRow',
>             handle: ".handle",
>             onEnd({newIndex, oldIndex}) {
>                 const rowSelected = _self.slots.splice(oldIndex,1)[0];
>                 _self.slots.splice(newIndex, 0, rowSelected);
>             }
>         });
>     }
> ```

Answer (score 3):

I'm using SortableJS with Nuxt. The shortest solution I found was to register a directive with `Vue.directive`:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import {Sortable} from 'sortablejs';
Vue.directive("sortableDataTable", {
  bind(el, binding, vnode) {
    const options = {
      animation: 150,
      onUpdate(event) {
        vnode.child.$emit('sorted', event)
      }
    }
    Sortable.create(el.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0], options)
  }
})
```

Now I can use the `v-sortable-data-table` directive in a `v-data-table`:

```html
  <v-data-table
    v-sortable-data-table
    :items="items"
    :headers="headers"
    item-key="id"
  >
  </v-data-table>
```

Note that the directive is registered as `sortableDataTable` but is used as `v-sortable-data-table` (camelCase is converted to kebab-case and must be prefixed with 'v-' when used).

Comment: works great, really simple implementation also